# Wrong external screen detection after Bionic update

Tags: display, display-resolution

I use a Dell laptop latitude 5590 with Bionic 18.04
I use an external screen to extend my laptop screen. It is a Philips 220E (22") with 1920x1080-60Hz capability.

After update my Bionic OS yesterday (7th jan), this morning (8th jan), the external screen resolution has bad 1024x768 resolution.  In *Settings/Screens*, it show *RTK 7* instead *Philips Consumer Electronics Company 22"*
It is connected to VGA connector but *xrandr* mention *DP-1 connected*.

I tried to force 1600x900 or 1920x1080 resolution with xrandr as mention at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions, but without success, resolution is changing but is still not good.

Note that this screen work fine if I connect to desktop computer, and I connected a Dell 20" screen on my laptop and it is correctly recognized.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I own the same Dell and the same Philips monitor. I still can't get the proper resolution. Kernel version is 5.15.0-56-generic. Neither Xorg or Wayland works.

Comment: No, I use now a recent Dell monitor, sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works again after Ubuntu upgrade … 4.15.0-45-generic #48 :-)
and works bad after Ubuntu upgrade … 4.15.0-46-generic #49 :-(